# Firebase Realtime Database - Loading documents depending on timestamp in intervals

Tags: firebase, flutter

I would like to build a Postfeed using Flutter and Firebase.

The way it should work is that I have a document in Firebase called 'Posts'. Each post will have an attribute with a timestamp. In the feed people should see the latest 10 posts and then click a button at the bottom of the feed to load 10 more.

My problem is that I don't want to load all posts from the database and then filter it, because with time this wouldn't scale as more posts are added.

Is there a way to access the posts document in firebase's realtime database - in intervals, hence always loading the last recent 10 at a time?

Or what would be the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: you should use a pagination library for best practice. example-> https://pub.dev/packages/pagination

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand the library correctly, it wouldn't solve my data load issue. Hence, I would still first get all posts from the real time data base and then display it, right? Hence, if I had millions of posts this could delay it significantly.

Comment: You say you're using the Firebase Realtime Database, but are talking about documents, which are a concept from Cloud Firestore. Either way: if you search for that tag name and `pagination`, you'll find that the topic has been covered regularly already. I recommend studying existing posts, and trying to get it working from that. If you get stuck along the way, post back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll be in a better position to help.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I will have a look at this.